# How does ecommerce tracking work for multiple currencies

Tags: ecommerce, google-tag-manager

I have a client based in the UK which sells from one website to multiple countries. I am setting up standard ecommerce tracking through GTM and wondering, if someone pays in USD, will GA recognise this and convert to my default currency GBP?? If not, does standard ecommerce recognise currency as a dataLayer variable??

Answer (score -1):

I have come across an article which explains how to set this up in GTM as it is not currently supported:
https://grantlucas.com/posts/2016/12/setting-currency-when-using-universal-analytics-and-google-tag-manager-ecommerce